# GCP : Conectar desde BigQuery una bd de una maquina en Compute Engine

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-bigquery

quisiera su orientación respecto a lo siguiente :
Como se puede realizar una conexion desde BigQuery a una base de datos Mysql que vive dentro de una maquina en compute engine, todo esto dentro del entorno GCP.

Agradecere alguna orientación respecto a como realizar esto, gracias.

Comment: Define "realizar una conexcion". Quieres hacer una migració de datos?

Comment: Crear un origen de datos en Bigquery que apunte hacia la base de datos mysql que esta dentro de la una vm en compute engine.